# How to get a drawable resource from subclass?

Tags: android

Firstable sorry for my bad english, In a subclass i want to get a drawable ressource, but an error rising like, nullObjectRefernce.I dont know how to fix this issue. If someone can help me. Thanks!

This is for android wear

```
public class DisplayManager extends MainActivity {

    private Drawable bulle_pleine;
    private int point;
    private String[] tabScore = {"0", "15", "30", "40", "EG", "AV","Jeu"};


    public void updateDisplayPoint(String player, int pt) {
        if (player == "nous") {
            btn_nous.setText(tabScore[pt]);
        }else{
            btn_eux.setText(tabScore[pt]);
        }
    }

    public void updateDisplayGame(String player, int ptGame) {
        Log.i("ptGame ", String.valueOf(ptGame));
        if (player == "nous") {
            switch (ptGame) {
                case 1:
                    bulle_pleine = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.bulle_pleine);
                    nous_jeux_1.setImageDrawable(bulle_pleine);
                    break;
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `DisplayManager` extend `MainActivity`? Is it actually being used as an `Activity`? That is, does it ever show on-screen itself?

Comment: I Nuri, it's just for use views like button, textArea ... maybe it's not the good way?

Comment: Then I would assume that you're directly instantiating `DisplayManager` yourself; i.e., you're doing something like `DisplayManager dm = new DisplayManager();`. You cannot do that with `Activity` classes and have them work correctly, which is why `getApplicationContext()` will throw a `NullPointerException` in `updateDisplayGame()`. Also, even if you correct that, the `Button`s that you're attempting to modify there are not the same instances that you see in `MainActivity`, so those will throw NPEs, too. If you really want a separate class to handle this stuff, you'll need to pass the...

Comment: ...`Button`s to it, either through a constructor, or a public method. The first step in fixing this is to remove `extends MainActivity` from `DisplayManager`'s declaration.

Comment: Ok Mike i try this thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ContextCompat.getDrawable` for getting drawable from resources

Simply use this

```
nous_jeux_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulle_pleine);
```

Comment: I Radesh he dont work 'code' java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Plectre as error say you dont initialize(findViewByid) for nous_jeux_1. if you want more help share full code of DisplayManager.java

Comment: in wich method of this class can i initialize ImageView nous_jeux_1 ?

Comment: @Plectre in onCreate() or first line in case 1

Comment: I add onCreate but it seems like method is not called

Comment: @Plectre oncreate() call automatically when you open activity. all your code must be in onCreate() if you new in android. please have more study about android develop. its not easy thing at start